# Tempusdominus datetimepicker open direction

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Is there a way to open the datetimepicker under the input instead of opening it above of the input? I know there are some pickers that have it in the box but I did not find such an option in this one.

Using version: `5.0.1`
https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

Comment: Every example on this page: https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/ opens under the input unless the input is close to the bottom of the viewport, in which case then it opens above it.

Comment: @gforce301 yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widgetPositioning option

```
myDatetimeInput.datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm',
    widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: 'bottom', // always opens to buttom direction
    },
});
```